# Can we equate general term of two equal summations provided limit goes from $0$ to $\infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

For example:

If $∑_{x=0}^{\infty}f(x)=∑_{x=0}^{\infty}g(x)∑_{x=0}^{\infty}f(x)=∑_{x=0}^{\infty}g(x)$, can we say $f(x)=g(x)f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$, or is there a possibility that they are not necessarily equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}=2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}$$